# Set-SFTPFile upload full directory

Tags: powershell, ssh, sftp

I need to upload full directory (with recourcive folders) to the server by sftp

```
#SSH
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

$sftpSession = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName $HostIP -Credential $Credentials

#Folders Paths
$FilePath = Get-ChildItem -Path uploading-folder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$SftpPath = "/home/new-folder"

# Upload the file to the SFTP path
Set-SFTPFile -SessionId ($sftpSession).SessionId -LocalFile $FilePath -RemotePath $SftpPath -Overwrite

#Disconnect all SFTP Sessions
Get-SFTPSession | % { Remove-SFTPSession -SessionId ($_.SessionId) }
```

But i cant upload folders inside folders (and filse in them). How can I upload full folder with files and folders inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Posh does not seem to support recursive operations. You have to code it on your own.

Quoting Reddit post [SFTP - How to upload an entire folder/directory instead of one file at a time?](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7zich7/comment/duoh7c8/):

```
# Get a recursive list of files in the target folder ($path).  
# Change the include to your needs,
# and remove the -Force if you don't want hidden files included
$path = "./Recursion test/"
$uploadFiles = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include "*" -Force

$session = New-SFTPSession (your args here)
$remoteFolder = Get-SFTPCurrentDirectory $sessoin.Index

Set-SFTPDirectoryPath $session.Index -Path $destinationPath
foreach ($item in $uploadFiles) {
    if ($item.GetType -eq [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
        New-SFTPDirectory $sessionIndex $item
    }
    else {
        $localFolder = $item.PSPath | Split-Path | Split-Path -Leaf
        if ($localFolder -ne $remoteFolder) {
            Set-SFTPCurrentDirectory $session.Index $localFolder
            $remoteFolder = $localFolder
        }
        Set-SFTPFile $session.Index $item.Name
    }
}
```

---

Or use another SFTP library that supports recursive operations.

Answer (score -1):

Code :

```
$folders =  @('D:\Shares\folderone\*.pdf','D:\Shares\foldertwo\*.pdf')
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem $folder
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Set-SFTPItem -SessionId $SFTPSession.SessionId -Path $file -Destination /upload -Verbose
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not *recursive*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).